# How can We used Twitter Direct mesage API in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I want the functionality to send Direct message from my website using twitter API

But I am getting an error,

> {"request":"/1.1/blocks/create.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}{"ids":
>          [2563195406,262571857,2525414911,293987080,1338863436,15052860,1470277314,122058685,1139173794
>           ,1381267824,225402247,274433814],"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,"pr
>           evious_cursor_str":"0"}

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write permission to send direct message so register your number in your twitter account and then change your app permission.